# My URL Data won't fill in my SQL data table Python

Tags: python, sql, database, api, pycharm

```
import json
import urllib
import sqlite3


def loading():
    url = 'https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?page=1'  # URL for API 1-5json_obj = urllib.urlopen(url)
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = json.load(response)  # loads the url and set it into data variable

    for item in data[0].keys():
        return data  # Get the keys
# def loading():
# print " LOADING API(s)"
# urllib.urlopen('https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?page=1')
# temp = json.dumps(data[1])
# print (json.dumps(data[1]))
# print (" ")
def createDB(data):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('comp.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    # Create table
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comp
        (id text primary key, type text, url text,created_at timestamp, company text, company_url text, location text, title text, description text, how_to_apply text, company_logo text
        )''')
    temp_values = list(tuple())
    for item in data:
        list_of_values = [v for k, v in item.items()]
        tuple_of_values = tuple(list_of_values)
        temp_values.append(tuple_of_values)


        #TO DO
        # Make sub sets for each category call
        # put in category for each ? in table
    c.executemany('INSERT INTO comp VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', temp_values)
    conn.commit()

def main():
    data = loading()
    createDB(data)

main()
```

I'm getting this compile error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/issac_rodriguez/PycharmProjects/N/Sprint2/database.py", line 43, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/issac_rodriguez/PycharmProjects/N/Sprint2/database.py", line 40, in main
    data = loading()
  File "/Users/issac_rodriguez/PycharmProjects/N/Sprint2/database.py", line 9, in loading
    data = json.load(response)  # loads the url and set it into data variable
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load'
```

Comment: Do you have a `json.py` in the same folder as the script?

Comment: im not sure how would I go about checking. I'm using Pycharm IDE

Comment: Pycharm can show you content of the directory in the project pane